Как освободить оперативную память в Python
В IDLE Python задаю большой вектор 'm', который занимает оперативную память. Потом перевожу его в вектор GPU 'm-gpu'. Затем очищаю вектор 'm' из оперативной памяти, и 'm_gpu' из памяти GPU, но оперативная RAM память ОЗУ освобождается не до конца (видно на скрине диспетчера задач). Когда закрываю окно IDLE, оперативная память освобождается до исходного состояния (на скрине не показано). Как освободить оперативную память ОЗУ? Вопрос не про видео-память, а про ОЗУ.
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
mempool = cp.get_default_memory_pool()
# Создание массива
m = np.arange(1e9)
# Перевод массива в Cupy
m_cp = cp.asarray(m)    
# Очистка оперативной памяти ОЗУ от массива 'm'
del m
# Очистка оперативной памяти GPU от массива 'm_cp'
m_cp = None     
mempool.free_all_blocks()



Фактически вы поставили на удаление, но не удалили. Сборщик мусора работает не постоянно, а по какому-то своему внутреннему алгоритмы, так что очистка памяти не произойдёт тут и сейчас. Попробуйте принудительно вызвать сборщик мусора - gc.collect().

@Amgarak факт в том, что если убрать часть кода, связанную с GPU, то оперативная память освобождается полностью до исходной (на скрине виден спуск). Когда появляется вектор Cupy, задействуется дополнительное ОЗУ (дельта между исходным и конечным). Использование 'gc.collect()' не помогает

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76024905/14775762

Значит проблема в либе cupy ‍♀️ вижу по ссылке от Станислава что-то такое и обсуждают.

Там везде обсуждают видеопамять. У меня вопрос про RAM память не видеокарты

@bluesky, драйвер видеокарты может выделять обычную память, чтобы сделать данные из карты доступными обычному коду на CPU. Попробуйте освободить видеопамять, скорее всего это очистит и обычную память. Всё же ваши проблемы связаны с картой.

Освобождение памяти и подчистка мусора означают, что новые создаваемые объекты смогут ее переиспользовать и не придется запрашивать еще памяти у системы, а не то, что эта память будет обязательно сразу возвращаться обратно системе. Хотите самостоятельно забирать и возвращать память в систему - используйте языки с ручным управлением памятью, такие как С/C++, и дергайте там функции прямой работы с виртуальной памятью процесса VirtualAlloc c VirtualFree  - тогда каждый вызов будет четко виден на графике.

Да, кажется была такая тема, что сама среда исполнения уже не отдаст память системе, пока процесс не завершится. Только я не помню, это в Питоне были или в C# или в них обоих )  Процесс может использовать эту память, а отдать системе не может.
